# Which Java distribution is best for Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

There was time I used AdoptOpenJDK or the embeded Java which comes bundled with Android Studio, but have not noticed difference. Looking at the preferences for gradle there is a lot of other distributions. On the internet I have read that some of them have patches for security and performance.

[image: java distributions offered by Android Studio]

so which one is best for Android? and why AdoptOpenJDK is missing from the list?

Answer (score 1):

They are simply maintained by their publishers respectively and they are all derived from OpenJDK which developed by Oracle.

I would recommend OpenJDK since it's the base for all of the other "flavours" and all of them gets the same bug fixes & security patches again deriving from OpenJDK.

Comment: Any ideas why Android Studio does not offer OpenJDK 11?

Comment: I believe Android Studio offers latest versions of each one of them, probably other companies than Oracle might not supporting every release but that just my own two cents.